# XML parsing help for C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm getting my feet wet with linq to xml, and I have the data in memory but the following code is running without error, but without adding my objects to the data point list (the end of the procedure below). If I had to guess I'd say something is wrong with my querying, returning no nodes. Here's a sample of the xml:

```
<results>
            <quote date="2012-02-07">
              <Date>2012-02-07</Date>
              <Open>44.76</Open>
              <High>44.88</High>
              <Low>44.22</Low>
              <Close>44.60</Close>
              <Volume>2547400</Volume>
              <Adj_Close>44.60</Adj_Close>
            </quote>
```

And here's my linq and relevant code:

```
List<IDataPoint> dataPointList = new List<IDataPoint>();
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AddressString);

var makeInfo =
                    from s in doc.Elements("quote")
                    where s.Element("Date") != null && s.Element("Open") != null
                        && s.Element("High") != null && s.Element("Low") != null
                        && s.Element("Close") != null && s.Element("Volume") != null
                        && !s.Element("Open").Value.Equals("") && !s.Element("High").Value.Equals("")
                        && !s.Element("Low").Value.Equals("") && !s.Element("Close").Value.Equals("")
                    select new DailyPricingVolDP(symbol, (DateTime)s.Element("Date"),
                        (double)s.Element("Open"),
                        (double)s.Element("High"),
                        (double)s.Element("Low"),
                        (double)s.Element("Close"),
                        (long)s.Element("Volume"));

                foreach (var item in makeInfo)
                {
                    dataPointList.Add(item);
                }
```

Comment: when you put a breakpoint at the foreach what is inside makeInfo?

Comment: @MarkW Under makeInfo>Results View "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: where is symbol variable coming from?  I'm assuming DailyPricingVolDP inherits interface IDataPoint, is that correct?

Comment: @MarkW The symbol variable is in code I didn't show... I'm parsing it out of the address string... that wouldn't impact the xml though, right?

Comment: The issue is probably the xml is not formatted properly.

Comment: @Mark W I needed to use "Descendants" not "elements", thx though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure XDocument.Elements() only returns direct children, and based on your XML doc.Elements("quote") will not match anything.  Use XDocument.Decendants().

I.E. doc.Descendants("quote")

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var makeInfo = 
                    from s in doc.Element("result").Elements("quote") 
                    where s.Element("Date") != null && s.Element("Open") != null 
                        && s.Element("High") != null && s.Element("Low") != null 
                        && s.Element("Close") != null && s.Element("Volume") != null 
                        && !s.Element("Open").Value.Equals("") && !s.Element("High").Value.Equals("") 
                        && !s.Element("Low").Value.Equals("") && !s.Element("Close").Value.Equals("") 
                    select new DailyPricingVolDP(symbol, (DateTime)s.Element("Date"), 
                        (double)s.Element("Open"), 
                        (double)s.Element("High"), 
                        (double)s.Element("Low"), 
                        (double)s.Element("Close"), 
                        (long)s.Element("Volume"));
```

I'd also recommend writing, for example, `s.Element("Open").Value != string.Empty` instead of `!s.Element("Open").Value.Equals("")`, but that's a stylistic thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it on my own but thanks for the quick help...

```
doc.Elements("quote")
```

needs to be:

```
doc.Descendants("quote")
```

and it works as expected. Thanks again..